# operator++ для node в List'е

Tags: c++

```
template <typename ITEM>
class List
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        ITEM item;
        struct node* next;
    };
    node* head;
    ...
}
```

Надо, чтобы внутри функций классов работало:

```
node* iter = head;
++iter;
```

Как перегрузить operator++?

Comment: friend node& operator++ (node& iter) {iter=(*iter.p); return iter;};
++(*iter); работает. Но как перенести определение за пределы объявления класса?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Как перегрузить operator++?
>
> как перенести определение за пределы объявления класса?

Это делается за счет введения класса-итератора, например так:

```
template <typename ITEM>
class List{
  ...
  class Iterator{
    node*ptr;
    ...
    Iterator( node*ptr = NULL ) : ptr( ptr ){}
    ITEM*operator->( void ){ return &ptr->item; }
    iterator&operator++( void ){ ptr = ptr->next; return *this; }
    iterator operator++( int ){
      node*result;
      //
      result = ptr;
      ptr = ptr->next;
      return result;
    }
    ...
  };
  iterator begin( void ){ return head; }
  ...
};
```

Здесь `Iterator` - класс-обертка над указателем `node*`, у которого есть перегруженные операторы `->` и оба `++`. В программе вместо `node*` нужно будет просто использовать `Iterator`, тогда он будет работать как ожидалось, с плюсами.

Comment: @mega, поскольку я пишу на Си, меня всегда интересовало - такая (и подобные ей) реализация итераторов - это чисто демонстрационный пример или реальные реализации пишут тоже так?

Поясню, меня в такой штуке беспокоит удаление элементов списка при использовании нескольких итераторов (и не только).

Comment: Если рассматривать `STL`, то этот пример к ней очень близок, только там сам класс итератора вынесен за пределы списка. Но это, конечно демонстрация с минимумом функционала. Если использовать объекты такого класса в качестве указателя, то проблема удаления элементов списка при наличии экземпляров-итераторов будет схожа с проблемой его удаления при наличии на него обычных ссылок. Т.е. я пока не вижу особых причин для беспокойства. Или я Вас не так понял?

Comment: @mega, Вы меня поняли правильно. 

Существенная разница между обычными ссылками и итераторами чисто психологического плана. Итераторы **выглядят** безопасными, а явные указатели нет. Поэтому итераторы в большей степени провоцируют скрытые логические ошибки (к демо не относится).

Кстати, сам налетел на это (к счастью быстро обнаружил) в списках Java.

Comment: Согласен! Но этот "психологический обман" имеет место быть и при использовании любого неисследованного класса. Или класса, реакция которого на какие-то абстрактные действия как с его прототипом недостаточно изучены. Например: если у итератора не переписать опреатор &, то 2 аналогичных по природе действия с прототипом и его оберткой могут привести к логической ошибке, если по каким-то причинам, смещение указателя в итераторе будет отлично от нуля:

 void**p = (void*)&pNode;
 void**q = (void*)&It;
Вот ни кому не пожелаю такую искать :)

Comment: @mega, отличный пример, демонстрирующий сложность С++.

Answer (score 0):

Хороший пример приведен тут: [перегрузка операторов](http://www.amse.ru/courses/cpp2/2010_11_22.html).